# There is an error converting date/time to string

Tags: c#, mysql, database

It was working in a computer that I was using in school however when I transferred it to my personal laptop, it suddenly got an error.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myCon"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Student VALUES (@stu_fname, @stu_lname, @Address, @Phone, @Email, @DateOfBirth, @UserName, @PassWord, @DateAdded)", con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stu_fname", TxtFN.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stu_lname", TxtLN.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", TxtAddress.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", TxtPhone.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", TxtDateOfBirth.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", TxtUsername.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PassWord", TxtPassword.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAdded", DateTime.Now);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Success boi");
        con.Close();
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include the full exception in your question, please? At a guess, it's because you're using a date type in the database, and trying to insert a string.

Comment: Please include the DDL for the table.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.' this is the exception and the data type that im using is datetime for the DateAdded and date for DateOfBirth

Comment: Is this mysql or SQL Server? What value you have in `TxtDateOfBirth.Text` ?

Comment: For the     TxtDateOfBirth.Text I have a datepicker in the windows form

Comment: Did you debug the code? What value you have in TxtDateOfBirth.Text when you debug the code? Also is there the difference in the way the date is displayed in System Tray between school computer and the laptop?

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlConnection and SqlCommand are both disposable, so should be in `using` blocks. Once you've done that you won't needs to close the connection because the dispose will take care of that. I'd also suggest taking a look at [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: The DateAdded datetime isn't displayed in the UI though and it's only stored in the SQL database

Comment: For `DatePicker` use `.Value` property for getting correct `DateTime` value. `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", DateOfBirthDatePicker.Value);`

Answer (score 1):

Try!

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAdded", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

Or convert string to date.

```
 DateTime dateOfbirth = DateTime.ParseExact(TxtDateOfBirth.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAdded",.TxtDateOfBirth.value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));//add format you want.
 //Leaving it at TxtDateOfBirth.value  system date and time format will be inserted